# Security protocol to allow only one mobile app requests to server

Tags: web-services, security

Is there a well proven security protocol to use to ensure that the request sent to my web server comes from a specific mobile application (The mobile application should be deployed in many phones)?

If not, what is the best practice?

Comment: Anything placed on a users phone should be assumed to be compromisable by that user. Maybe if you define what specific threats you're trying to protect yourself against, we may be able to offer some suggestions.

Comment: Some options would be to use an RSA token or to pre-authenticate the user by sending him/her a temporary token by SMS, which should be passed back by the mobile app in the server request, together with some secret user PIN (see the security model of most bank account access). Anyway, you can not ensure from which application the request comes from. It will just reach to one of the layers of your server application infrastructure, parsed by following a set of exclusion rules and be allowed/denied to the next server application layer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever All I want is to protect my web service from getting any random requests that would create some unneeded resources in my server.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTPS in your Server end and Having an Access Token in all requests coming to your web server may allow you to restrict.

You can have the Access Token configured in your mobile app. Any request coming to the web server without a valid Access Token is simply considered malicious.